# Linear algebra text after abstract algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request

I wonder whether there exists a linear algebra text dealing the materials of linear algebra suitably under the assumption that the reader is familiar with basic abstract algebra.

I know, strictly speaking, linear algebra is a subtopic of abstract algebra. But modern text books often deal them briefly, under the section of 'vector space'. But the scale of topics in linear algebra is far more than what one section can contained.

Comment: Try ''Topic in Algebra by I. N. Herstein". Because this book first of all covers Groups, then Rings and some Field theory, then they introduces Vector Space and Linear Trasformation.

Comment: I wrote something on "linear algebra after abstract algebra" in my mind:  https://cubicbear.github.io/doc/Linear_Algebra_Problems.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There's a Dover paperback entitled *Linear Algebra and Group Theory*.

See [here](https://a.co/d/3Pkxkz2).

These books are notoriously affordable (and usually pretty good).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this one . . .

Roman, Advanced Linear Algebra, 3rd Ed (2008)

From the preface:

> This book is a thorough introduction to linear algebra, for the graduate or
>   advanced undergraduate student. Prerequisites are limited to a knowledge of the
>   basic properties of matrices and determinants. However, since we cover the
>   basics of vector spaces and linear transformations rather rapidly, a prior course in linear algebra (even at the sophomore level), along with a certain measure of “mathematical maturity,” is highly desirable.
>
> Chapter $0$ contains a summary of certain topics in modern algebra that are
>   required for the sequel. This chapter should be skimmed quickly and then used
>   primarily as a reference.

Chapter $1$ starts with:

> **Definition**: Let $F$ be a field, whose elements are referred to as **scalars**. A vector space over $F$  is a nonempty set $V$, whose elements are referred to as **vectors**, together with two operations (rest snipped).

Note that $F$ is an *arbitrary* field, so the author assumes that the student is familiar with that concept.

Answer (score -1):

Hungerford's *Algebra* is an abstract algebra book that covers linear algebra under assumption that you know quite a bit of abstract algebra first.  To be specific, it's first $6$ chapters are: "Groups", "Structure of Groups", "Rings", "Modules", "Fields and Galois Theory", and "Structure of Fields".

Linear algebra is covered fairly comprehensively in the seventh chapter: matrices and linear maps, determinants, matrix similarity, eigenvectors and eigenvalues, Jordan canonical form, Smith normal form, etc.